# Firebase user.delete() method works but with error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, angular10

I am using angular, and have an application that stores user details, and login info. When trying to delete a user, I am first deleting all the user related information. Then asking the user to re-authenticate themselves, after authentication, user gets logged out, and their basic details fetched to show profile id deleted followed by their sign-in info using user.delete().

All this works as expected, but at the end I am getting an error. Why am I am getting this error even when I have already logged out the user of the application.

Error Message: `{code: "auth/user-token-expired", message: "The user's credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again.", a: null}`

My code -

```
  deleteAccount(){
    var userToDelete = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    this.logout();
    this.store.dispatch(UI.StartAppLoad({status:'Deleting User Details...'}));

    this.userService.DeleteUser(userToDelete.uid)
    .then((res)=>{
      console.log(res);
    }).catch(this.HandleError.bind(this));

    userToDelete.delete().then(
      (res)=>{
        console.log(res);
        this.uiService.showSnackbar('User Account Deleted',null,3000);
        this.store.dispatch(UI.LoadApp());
      }
    ).catch(this.HandleError.bind(this));
  }

  logout() {
    this.afAuth.signOut();
  }
```

where, `HandleError` is used to display the Error Message in a snackbar.

`deleteAccount()` is called after the user successfully authenticates themselves.

Instead of getting the error message displayed, I want to display the message `'User Account Deleted'`.

Entire Flow -

```
  onDeleteAccount(){
    const confirmResult = this.uiService.showConfirm({
      isDanger:true,
      title:'Delete Account?',
      content:'All your user account data will be permamnently deleted.'+
              ' You will need to create a new account later. Are you sure you want to continue?',
      okText:'Delete'
    });
    confirmResult.subscribe(async isDelete=>{
      if(isDelete){
        this.store.dispatch(UI.StartAppLoad({status:'Deleting Excercise Data...'}));
        const isResetDone = await this.trainingService.resetPastExercise();
        if(isResetDone){
          this.store.dispatch(UI.StartAppLoad({status:'Deleting Follow list...'}));
          this.userService.clearFollowList();
          this.authService.actionToPerform.next(actions.Delete_Account);
          this.store.dispatch(UI.LoadApp());
          this.router.navigate([AppRoutes.ReAuthenticate]);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Authenticate Page's `submit()` method:

```
this.authService.reauthenticate({
  email:form.value.email,
  password:form.value.password
});

this.authService.deleteAccount();
```

AuthService:

```
reauthenticate(authdata: AuthData) {
    this.store.dispatch(UI.StartLoading());
    var credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(
      authdata.email,
      authdata.password
    );
    this.afAuth.currentUser.then((user) => {
      user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential)
        .then((res)=>{
          this.prevPwd = authdata.password;
          console.log(res);
          this.store.dispatch(UI.StopLoading());
        })
        .catch(this.HandleError.bind(this))
    });
  }
```

And then the above method `deleteAccount()`

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user.md#userdelete), this happens because:

> `delete()` is a security-sensitive operation that **requires the user to
> have recently signed in**.

The doc also indicates that:

> If this requirement isn't met, ask the user
> to authenticate again and then call `firebase.User.reauthenticateWithCredential`.

So, you need to handle this specific error and do as indicated by the doc, i.e. "ask the user to authenticate again and then call [`reauthenticateWithCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#reauthenticatewithcredential)."

Comment: Hi, I have called `user.reauthenticateWithCredential()` before this method, and only if the user has successfully authenticated themselves, this method is being called.

Comment: Please check the post. I have added the entire flow.

Comment: If I am not mistaking, I don't see any place in your code where you call `reauthenticateWithCredential()`.

Comment: Sorry, I just missed adding that part here. it is called from within the `reauthenticate()` method. \n